# Selenium with Python Framework few queries

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I m working on Selenium with Java now I m thinking about selenium with Python,
Before I start I have few queries as:

1.is Python +Selenium will work with Jenkins
2.Do we have framework like page object model in Python+Selenium(Need to design for Multilanguae )
3.Can we have features like screenshots?
4.Do we have a report mechanism

Appreciate your response

Comment: Voted to close because this question, "Needs more focus. This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Answer (score 0):

1. Jenkins is CI/CD tool, which is language agnostic, doesn't matter if you working in JAVA, python, C# or C++, it will work with any programming language.
2. Again POM is a pattern that helps you to manage/write better code, it is also language agnostic. You can use it with programming language, any test framework.
3. Yes, selenium webdriver itself is capable of taking screenshots and incorporate it within your project
4. Yes, there are many [allure report](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python) is just one of them